# classcast exception while adding rows to table layout

Tags: android, dynamic, row, tablelayout, classcastexception

problem solved: i should have cleaned the project. thanks for the answers

hey guys i'm trying to add rows to table layout durign execution but it gives an error

12-02 20:29:47.588: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(569): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.project.andr/com.project.andr.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ScrollView

here is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:id="@+id/myTableLayout" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"> 
 <TableRow 
      android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"> 

      <Button android:text="Static Button" android:id="@+id/myButton"/> 
 </TableRow> 
</TableLayout>
```

and here is my java code

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
  TableLayout tl = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.myTableLayout); 
     /* Create a new row to be added. */ 
     TableRow tr = new TableRow(this); 
     tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams( 
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); 
          /* Create a Button to be the row-content. */ 
          Button b = new Button(this); 
          b.setText("Dynamic Button"); 
          b.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams( 
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); 
          /* Add Button to row. */ 
          tr.addView(b); 
/* Add row to TableLayout. */ 
      tl.addView(tr,new TableLayout.LayoutParams( 
          LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 
          LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
      setContentView(tl);
```

Comment: What line of code is the error pointing to?

Comment: The error mentioned a ScrollView? I can't see any scrollview in your code. If you know where that comes from, you probably find your answer

Comment: Try to clean & build your project, because with this layout and this code, you cannot get ClassCastException due to a ScrollView...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the class cast exception is with your ScrollView, not your TableLayout. Give your whole stack trace or check to make sure you're using your ScrollView properly.

Answer (score 0):

cleaning the project did the work for me.